# Wrong path of VIEW_ROOT

Tags: php

I'm requiring some php files but having trouble getting the the correct path of VIEW_ROOT. With both APP_ROOT and VIEW_ROOT I'm getting the same path..

[image: Folder structure]

Here is my: config.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

define('APP_ROOT', __DIR__);
define('VIEW_ROOT', APP_ROOT . '/views');
define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/traderMVC/');

echo APP_ROOT;
echo VIEW_ROOT;
```

... and here is my index.php

```
require 'app/config.php';
require VIEW_ROOT .'/home.php';
```

.. and here os error message:

```
Warning: require(C:\laragon\www\traderMVC\app/views/home.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\laragon\www\traderMVC\index.php on line 7

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\laragon\www\traderMVC\app/views/home.php' (include_path='.;C:/laragon/etc/php/pear') in C:\laragon\www\traderMVC\index.php on line 7
```

echo of APP_ROOT and VIEW_ROOT

```
C:\laragon\www\traderMVC\app
C:\laragon\www\traderMVC\app
```

Comment: Well, your `views` folder is outside the `app` folder

Comment: `define('VIEW_ROOT', APP_ROOT . '../views');`

Comment: better have the config in your root folder..

Comment: @Jeff This does not work. Echo: C:\laragon\www\traderMVC\app../views

Comment: ok, then `/../views` or better `DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR.'views'`

Comment: Wohaaaa... :) Thank you!

Comment: you may accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: you **need** to accept jeff's answer if it solved your problem

Comment: thanks, @MehdiBounya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since your `views` folder isn't below your `config.php` file, but on the same level, change

```
define('VIEW_ROOT', APP_ROOT . '/views');
```

to

```
define('VIEW_ROOT', APP_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR.'views');
```

which is nearly the same as

```
define('VIEW_ROOT', APP_ROOT . '/../views');
```

but just aware of the system-specific directory seperators.
Most systems will cope with a mix of `/` and `\`. Some will not.
Still I encurage you to have the config somewhere in the root, as it will retain you of such problems.